# If statement (button not clicked)

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, click

I want to hide an element if it is clicked outside the element it self. als But it can't be closed if the menu button is clicked.

Now I have the following code:

```
$(document).mouseup(function test (e) {
  var button = $('.menu-button').data('clicked', true);
  var container = $(".sf-menu");
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0 && button.data('clicked') == false) {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

But the problem seems to be in:

```
button.data('clicked') == false)
```

How to write this code correctly?

Thnx!

Comment: try console logging button.data('clicked') and see if it is a string or a boolean - if you want to know what was clicked, look at e.target - also stop setting the clicked to true before testing if it is false

Comment: Hard to understand what you're trying to achieve, but what I see is that you set data clicked to true all the time, so can't be false

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `$(button).data('clicked')` and not  `button.data('clicked')` as `button` will contain the jquery object returned by `$('.menu-button').data('clicked', true);`

```
$(document).mouseup(function test (e) {
  var button = $('.menu-button').data('clicked', true);
  var container = $(".sf-menu");
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0 && $(button).data('clicked') == false) {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you get a chance to check the answer. Let me know if you face any problems

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
var button = $('.menu-button').data('clicked', true);
```

with

```
var button = $('.menu-button').data('clicked', button.is(e.target));
```